# empty an existing array in ksh

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, ksh

I have script which stores the list of files in an array as shown below

```
set -A my_array $(ls -tr $INPUT_DIRECTORY/*)
```

I have to empty this `my_array` variable to use it for other purpose. I cannot declare another new array.

Is there any way to clear the content of the array and reuse it again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using `set -A` ... to clear the array you could issue:

```
set -A my_array
```

To re-use the array:

```
set -A my_array $(command to generate new data set)
```

For example:

```
$ cd /
$ set -A my_array $('ls' -tr sys)
$ echo ${my_array[@]}
kernel devices module bus class fs block power firmware dev
$ set -A my_array $('ls' -tr var)
$ echo ${my_array[@]}
opt crash X11R6 mail games yp spool lib adm cache lock tmp log run
$ set -A my_array
$ echo ${my_array[@]}
  <<no output>>
```

Or you could use a looping construct, eg:

```
for i in ${!my_array[@]}
do
    unset my_array[${i}]
done
```

For example:

```
$ set -A my_array $('ls' -tr var)
$ echo ${my_array[@]}
opt crash X11R6 mail games yp spool lib adm cache lock tmp log run
$ for i in ${!my_array[@]}
do
    unset my_array[${i}]
done
$ echo ${my_array[@]}
  <<no output>>
```